# How to get a color from the current theme programmatically in Android (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to get some default theme color values programmatically (e.g. windowBackground, colorPrimary). I'm executing the code from an Activity. My target android **API is 21**. I'm using a `Theme.Material theme`. I've tried:

```
var attributeValue = new Android.Util.TypedValue();
this.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Resource.Attribute.colorPrimary, attributeValue, true)
```

with different resource identifier, but i always get a `Android.Util.DataType.Null` value.

Comment: did you check my answer ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code I have tested

For `WindowBackground` :

**Code :**

```
Android.Util.TypedValue a = new Android.Util.TypedValue();
Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.WindowBackground, a , true);
var windowBackgroundDrawable = Application.Context.GetDrawable(a.ResourceId);      
var windowBackgroundColor = ((Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable)windowBackgroundD‌​rawable).Color;
```

**Output My Case is :**  `FAFAFA`

For `ColorPrimary` use this :

**Code :**

```
Android.Util.TypedValue a = new Android.Util.TypedValue();
Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.ColorPrimary, a , true);
var colorPrimarya = Application.Context.GetDrawable(a.ResourceId);      
var colorPrimary = ((Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable) colorPrimarya).Color;
```

**Output My Case is :**  `0072BA`

Comment: Thanks. I saw what i was missing. Your code needed some improvements to get the actual color: _var windowBackgroundDrawable = Application.Context.GetDrawable(a.ResourceId);
var windowBackgroundColor = ((Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable)windowBackgroundDrawable).Color;_ Could you add it to your solution?

Comment: Yes, of cause. Please, update the second snippet as well. So it can be consistent.

Comment: And even if it looks pedantic, please fix the prefixes with colorPrimary