# How to get boolean from custom boolean attribute for current theme?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-theme

I am setting custom attribute with Boolean format in my theme.

```
<attr name="isCompound" format="boolean" />
```

When I am trying to retrieve this attribute in my code using following

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.isCompound, typedValue, true);
if(typedValue.data) {
    ...
}
```

I get error that typedValue.data (int) can not be converted to Boolean. My question is how do I get Boolean value isCompound from the current theme?

Comment: "The _data_ field holds 0 or 1 that was originally specified as 'false' or 'true'." – https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue#TYPE_INT_BOOLEAN.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting unexpected results with that, though. Make certain to test it. I'm not sure if I'm just doing something stupid in my test, or if it's something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Mike M. for the comment

> Blockquote "The data field holds 0 or 1 that was originally specified as "false" or "true"." – https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue#TYPE_INT_BOOLEAN

Document says that it returns 1 for true and 0 for false. But when I test it returns -1 for true and 0 for false.

I guess, safe way would be to check for false.

Comment: Exactly my findings, as well. And, looking at some framework source examples, that's what they do, too; check for false. You might also want to check the return from the `resolveAttribute()` call. It returns a `boolean` indicating whether it could resolve the attribute. Just FYI.

Comment: no need to check for returned boolean value as default is false

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased that differently. I just meant that you might want to check that if you need to know if `isCompound` has been explicitly set in the given theme. I'm not sure of your exact requirements.